# Compare a list of lists and display result using OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, opencv, computer-vision

I have two list of lists that I want to compare element by element first.

```
a=[[0,0,0,0,3],[1,2]]  # This is the key (list of list)
b=[[0,0,0,2,3],[1,0]]  # This is the list of list I want to compare against the key list
```

I also have an image that has 5 rows (first rectangle) (because `a[0]` has 5 elements) and 2 rows (second rectangle) (because `a[1]` has 2 elements)

[image: Main Image]

For the following image, I know the corner points and the height of each individual rows. These are stored in another list. `xyh=[[115,60,70],[350,55,70]]`

What I would like to do is compare my list `b` against `a` and if they match eg `a[0][0]=b[0][0]` then the text "match" will be displayed in the first first column's first row, if they don't match then the element from the list `a` will be displayed.

This is the expected result at the end.

[image: Expected result]

My MWE:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

total_elements=7
a=[[0,0,0,0,3],[1,2]]  # This is the key (list of list)
b=[[0,0,0,2,3],[1,0]]  # This is the list of list I want to compare against the key list
xyh=[[115,60,70],[350,55,70]] # List for the top-right corner points of the columns and the height of each rows.

img=img=cv2.imread('1.jpg')
imgFinal=img.copy()

# How do I loop over all three list of lists and then display the result in imgFinal?






cv2.imshow('Expected Result',imgFinal)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the iterating, I'd use Python's built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip) function, so you can iterate the elements of all lists at the same time. The rest is simple value checking and putting the correct text to the image via [`cv2.putText`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga5126f47f883d730f633d74f07456c576). I first thought about using NumPy for the value checking, but since you have to use loops anyway for putting the text, all logic can be placed inside the loops.

Here's my full code:

```py
import cv2

# Lists
a = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 3], [1, 2]]
b = [[0, 0, 0, 2, 3], [1, 0]]
xyh = [[115, 60, 70], [350, 55, 70]]

# Original image and copy
img = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
imgFinal = img.copy()

# Iterate elements of all lists at the same time
for first_image, second_image, coords in zip(a, b, xyh):

    # Get initial x, y coordinates for the current image
    x = coords[0] - 60
    y = coords[1] + int(coords[2] / 2)

    # Iterate elements in each image
    for image_a, image_b in zip(first_image, second_image):

        # Put correct text to the image
        if image_a == image_b:
            imgFinal = cv2.putText(imgFinal, 'Match', (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1)
        else:
            imgFinal = cv2.putText(imgFinal, str(image_a), (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1)

        # Increment y coordinate to next row
        y = y + coords[2]

# Output
cv2.imshow('Expected Result', imgFinal)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And that'd be output:

[image: Output]

OpenCV has only limited support for text rendering, so the text doesn't look that nice.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.5
OpenCV:      4.4.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Just curious, I knew how to do it for a single list but how did you know to use zip? What is zip?

Comment: I linked to the [documentation of the `zip` command](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip) in answer. From there: _Returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables._